# Multiple Dropdown lists for Birth Date ... single line

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code that has a dropdown for month, Day, and Year for selecting Birth date components. The dropdown works but I would like them to appear on a single line (same line) ... what can I do?

```
<div id="birthDate">
        <asp:Label ID="Addr_BirthDt" Text="Born on:" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AddrB_Mth" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="AddrB_Mth_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AddrB_Day" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="01">01</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="02">02</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="03">03</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="04">04</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="05">05</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="06">06</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="07">07</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="08">08</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="09">09</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="11">11</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="12">12</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="13">13</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="14">14</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="16">16</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="17">17</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="18">18</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="19">19</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="20">20</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="21">21</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="22">22</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="23">23</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="24">24</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="25">25</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="26">26</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="27">27</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="28">28</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="29">29</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="30">30</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="31">31</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="AddrB_Year" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Value="1950">1950</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1951">1951</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1952">1952</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1953">1953</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1954">1954</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1955">1955</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1956">1956</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1957">1957</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1958">1958</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1959">1959</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1960">1960</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1961">1961</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1962">1962</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1963">1963</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1964">1964</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1965">1965</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1966">1966</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1967">1967</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1968">1968</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1969">1969</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1970">1970</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1971">1971</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1972">1972</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1973">1973</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1974">1974</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1975">1975</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1976">1976</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1977">1977</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1978">1978</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1979">1979</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1980">1980</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1981">1981</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1982">1982</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1983">1983</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1984">1984</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1985">1985</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1986">1986</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1987">1987</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1988">1988</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1989">1989</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1990">1990</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1991">1991</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1992">1992</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1993">1993</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1994">1994</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1995">1995</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1996">1996</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1997">1997</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1998">1998</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1999">1999</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2000">2000</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2001">2001</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2002">2002</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2003">2003</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2004">2004</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2005">2005</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2006">2006</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2007">2007</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2008">2008</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2009">2009</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2010">2010</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2011">2011</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2012">2012</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2013">2013</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2014">2014</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2015">2015</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2016">2016</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2017">2017</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2018">2018</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2019">2019</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2020">2020</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
         </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="submit" CssClass="btn blue wide" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" OnClick="btnSubmit_click"></asp:Button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- #modal-AddressInfo-edit .modal -->
<style>
    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
        right: 3.3em;
        top: 58%;
        width: 32px;
        margin: -10px 0 0 0;
        padding: 1px;
        height: 32px;
        left: 385px;
    }
    #birthDate {
        float: left;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: why dont you use ajax calender extender ?? [link](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/11/ajax-calendarextender-how-to-use.html)

Comment: Do you have anything that *keeps* them from being on the same line? The `select` element is an inline element, so normally they end up on the same line without doing anything at all.

Comment: Yikes. You know you can write a loop to create those values for you. Like Guffa said, the DDLs should be on one line unless there is not enough room for them in your div.

Comment: What do you mean by single line.. UI representation ?

Comment: I appreciate all of the comments, but I just wanted to know if anyone can see anything I am doing that is causing the dropdowns to appear on multiple lines, there should be enough room for them to all appear on the same line

Comment: Use the developer tools for whatever browser you're testing in - it should show you what is causing them to be pushed onto different lines.  I don't see anything in the code you've shown that would cause them to show on different lines.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel ***The above code is working fine; dropdownlists are already in a single line.***

Comment: @Win ***TRY USING CAPS LOCK TOO.*** Obviously, the code is not working just fine for the OP, or they wouldn't have posted the question. You know what I mean, jelly bean?

Comment: hi all, I put the dropdowns in a table and it corrected my issue, I realize there are different browsers and such which is why it is probable that someone else coding exactly the same way would get a different result. Also, I have used Ajax toolkit Calendar Extender but this is going to be used by many different users so they may not have those plugins. Thanks for all help!!

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel FYI tables are a *bad* idea for formatting. That is what CSS is for.